# How do I download a web app created on Firebase?

Tags: firebase

I have created my first app on Firebase and I would like to download it. How do I do it?

Comment: Are you talking about the data? There is an export JSON button in the dashboard.

Comment: I have made the app. I want to see it. I have a hacker plan.

Comment: To download the hosted assets, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26286339/firebase-code-pull

Answer (score 2):

Firebase is a platform for building realtime web applications. A "Firebase" is a realtime database that is hosted in the cloud. When you create a new "app" in the account dashboard that is essentially creating a cloud hosted Firebase. With this new Firebase and it's data URL you can use that to act as your application's backend. This URL is usually looks something like this: https://myapp.firebaseio.com/.

You use the URL as an API to store data into your Firebase. Every time data is updated Firebase will stream out the changes to the data in realtime.

So, the only thing to download in your Firebase is the data.

Comment: Your project contains a lot of files, info, and libraries. I accidentally broke few thing in the local version of my project and now I want to sync it with web version to get my latest working version back but I have no idea how to do that so here I am. Any ideas?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26286339/pull-lost-code-from-firebase-hosting-deployment