# Pull lost code from Firebase Hosting deployment

Tags: firebase-hosting

I need to pull down my code from a firebase hosted site, I created a site this past summer and no longer have the code locally on my laptop.   I would like to recode some of the pieces, but don't have the source code anymore (other than the javascript and css I can glean from the served pages).  I can't find a way to get the code from the firebase site, does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: it does seem strange to have to post questions on here, but that is what firebase asks users to do:  "For API questions and general technical help, we encourage you to use the Firebase tag on StackOverflow. We monitor the questions very closely, and using StackOverflow allows others to benefit from the answers"

Comment: Randal, it's not at all strange to post API or technical questions here. @Mooseman this isn't a documented or supported feature of Firebase and therefore isn't a documentation issue.

Comment: Firebase hosting just keeps the static resources of your web site, so it (normally) doesn't contain anything but JavaScript, CSS and HTML. What other code than JavaScript are you looking for?

Comment: The angular views that I wrote for the project

Answer (score 90, accepted):

You should of course add your own version control (e.g. git) to manage your revisions and backups so this doesn't occur.

There is a script you can run to download all the assets using the CLI. You can find the script and instructions [here](https://gist.github.com/mbleigh/9c8680cf319ace2f506f57380da66e7d). It can also be run using npx:

```
npx https://gist.github.com/mbleigh/9c8680cf319ace2f506f57380da66e7d <site_name>
```

Note that this only returns the compiled/rendered content from the [specified public folder](https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/full-config#specify-files-to-deply) and not any precompiled source you may have had on the development machine.

Since your files are static assets, you could also scrape them using wget. This is inferior for advanced apps as you'll get the rendered content and not the source:

```
wget -r -np https://<YOURAPPNAME>.firebaseapp.com
```

Read more on scraping web sites here: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/100570/getting-files-all-at-once-from-a-web-page-using-curl

Comment: Interestingly, "firebase deploy" doesn't seem to deploy my entire project (modulo the "ignore" setting in firebase.json), only the resources needed by my index.html file.

Comment: Firebase deploy does upload all the files, wget just might only scrape the ones it can access through your index.html

Comment: what is windows version of unix's wget `-r -np`? there is no -r for wget on windows 10

Comment: @robertotomás in W10 you can use unix packages through scoop.
First navigate to [scoop](https://scoop.sh) and install it. 
Then you'll get a `scoop` available in terminal (cmd), type `scoop install wget` and you'll be installing a linux package.
Finally if you are a dev and use W10 for work, I'd recommend you to enable dev tools.

Comment: I tried this method `wget -r -np https://<YOURAPPNAME>.firebaseapp.com` its working but not all files are downloading in macbook. Some folders are missing. Why? @Kato

Comment: Firebase hosting _only_ has the files from your public folder.  If you use webpack or any other build scripts, you've probably only uploaded your compiled files to hosting.  You can't download something that was never uploaded.

Comment: When using gist script from `mbleigh ` you should omit `https://` and `.firebaseapp.com`. It works seamlessly with just the app name.

Answer (score 8):

Maybe this answer is not exactly consisted with requested direction but in order to list the files which are being uploaded you could during the deploy use `--debug` switch:

```
firebase deploy --debug
```

With this option you will see the POST request. Something like that:

`>>> HTTP REQUEST POST https://deploy.firebase.com/firebase/yourapp/releases?token=XXX public=dist, version=-KE5UDaj7oCppckjEBaE, prefix=-KE5UDaj7oCppckjEBaE/, manifest=[path=404.html, object=404.html, path=scripts\main\main.html, object=scripts\main\main.html, path=scripts\scripts.d6106dbd.js, object=scripts\scripts.d6106dbd.js, path=scripts\vendor.68cdc83b.js, object=scripts\vendor.68cdc83b.js, path=styles\main.5b335e2d.css, object=styles\main.5b335e2d.css, path=styles\vendor.d41d8cd9.css, object=styles\vendor.d41d8cd9.css], rules=undefined
<<< HTTP RESPONSE 200 server=nginx, date=Wed, 30 Mar 2016 07:46:31 GMT, content-type=application/json; charset=utf-8, content-length=34, connection=close, access-control-allow-origin=*, access-control-allow-methods=GET, PUT, POST, DELETE, OPTIONS, strict-transport-security=max-age=31556926; includeSubDomains; preload, x-content-type-options=nosniff`

It might helps to trace what is rally uploaded to firebase hosting.

But I agree that the lack option to simple list the files on firebase hosting do not encourage to use this service.

Comment: I don't get any `object` or `path` in `HTTP REQUEST POST` if I run `firebase deploy --debug`. It seems like it doesn't work anymore

Comment: It's better & easier to use the hosting API to get your current version, and then list the files in that version.  The gist [1] is an example of how to do that
[1](https://gist.github.com/mbleigh/9c8680cf319ace2f506f57380da66e7d)

Answer (score 1):

I've tried https://stackoverflow.com/a/26287429/145122, but it doesn't download all the files. The following command worked for my website.

```
wget -mpEk https://yoursite.com
```

Comment: In case you run into wget command not found, make sure to install it with brew install wget.

Answer (score -9):

1. Its quite simple,the only thing you need to do is go to your hosted site.
2. right click and go to inspect element => debugger.There you will find a static folder.
3. relax,all your js files are there(front end only),you can copy your code.