# How can I see what files are deployed to Firebase hosting?

Tags: firebase, deployment, firebase-hosting

I'm using [Firebase hosting](https://www.firebase.com/docs/hosting/). I've deployed my site numerous times, with various iterations of the `ignore` setting in my `firebase.json` file. I'd like to check the correctness of this setting by getting a listing of what files are currently deployed to my Firebase. I can't see a way of doing that either from the command line `firebase` tool or from the web UI (e.g. at https://my-app.firebaseio.com/?page=Hosting).

Is it possible to list the currently hosted files?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26286339/firebase-code-pull

Comment: Seems Firebase Hosting is not matured in features to make this happen. Hope Firebase too dont break the hope as Parse

Comment: This is not a duplicate IMO wanting to list the files is not the same as wanting to download them.

Comment: @FirebaseTeam would be cool to have at least the list of files in the debug mode of firebase deploy