# How to clone a project from Firebase to another machine to work on it?

Tags: angularjs, firebase, firebase-hosting

I have deployed code over Firebase Hosting. Now I want to clone that code to my local machine to work on it, and deploy it again.

I am a newbie in Firebase Hosting so any clues for this are accepted.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If you accidentally lost access to your files, you may be able to recover them with the approach outlined here: [Firebase code pull](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26286339/firebase-code-pull/26287429#26287429).

But in general Firebase Hosting is not a replacement for a version control system, which is the preferred way of working on a single project from multiple systems.

Answer (score 0):

If you had static HTML-JS-CSS codes, you are most likely to get your code back using some tools/tricks/hacks. One of them is this-

https://gist.github.com/mbleigh/9c8680cf319ace2f506f57380da66e7d

But, if you had your code on Angular or something similar, you can't get the code back for obvious reasons.