# Get the content deployed to Firebase Hosting

Tags: firebase, firebase-hosting

In my PC, I deployed a few HTML files to my Firebase Hosting project.

I didn't save that code in any source code control.

Now, in another PC, I want to get that code that was previously deployed to Firebase and I don't find any option. I searched using the web app and using the `cli`. Is it not possible?

Something like:

```
firebase sync
```

Comment: There is no built-in feature for that, but you can typically get it by "crawling". See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26286339/firebase-code-pull