# Firebase - Collaborate Hosting Development

Tags: firebase, firebase-hosting

A guys shared a project with me.  Using my online / cloud based IDE, I created a new HTML5 project.

```
$ npm install -g firebase-tools
$ firebase login
$ firebase list
$ firebase use <shared-project>
$ firebase init
```

How do I get all the existing hosted files into my IDE so that I can collaborate on this project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to download the files from Firebase Hosting within the console. Firebase Hosting is in that sense no replacement for a proper version control system. The best way would be to set up such a version control system for sharing the code with the other developer.

If that's not an option, you an try crawling the site. See this answer: [Firebase code pull](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26286339/firebase-code-pull)

Answer (score 1):

I may be coming a bit late but just to add to what Frank said:

If the person you are collaborating with uses somekind of packaging solution like webpack, you won't be able to download the project's source files, since only the bundles will be publicly available.

My guess is that the only way to get the necessary files to collaborate on the project, is trough a proper versioning system, since even if you receive the whole project in a zip, you'd have no way of keeping it in sync with the rest of the team.