# Is it possible to download the deployed app from firebase?

Tags: firebase, firebase-hosting

My laptop just died and i didn't have any backup so all my work is lost. I have been working on a web app and i've been using firebase to host it. Is it possible to get back the source code from firebase?

Comment: As the answers have already said, pretty good chance that it's completely gone. Take this as a valuable lesson on why you should be using something like GitHub.... BUT, a couple questions to throw into the mix. How "dead" is your laptop? Just because it won't start doesn't mean you might not be able to pull out the hard drive and get files off that way. Also, what kind of website/app was deployed? I've deployed Angular sites before without disabling source maps, and I could see most of the original code I wrote in the deployed site.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [@Kato](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26286339/firebase-code-pull)

> There is no method available to grab your Firebase code. You should be
>   utilizing your own version control (e.g. git) to manage your revisions
>   and backups.

Answer (score 1):

If your code was on your laptop without any backups then your code is most likely gone.

For your next projects - start use GIT([github](https://github.com/explore) for example)