# How to pull a Firebase Bootstrap website code

Tags: firebase, hosting, firebase-hosting

I uploaded a website to Firebase hosting that I created using Bootstrap Studio.
Since it was in a local folder that I lost ( somehow all of my desktop programs disappeared), I tried recovering the deleted files but they are unrecoverable.

All I want is to edit few words and to host a website back online. How can I edit a website code that is hosted on Firebase without pulling the code?

Comment: There is nothing built into Firebase Hosting for either downloading the existing assets, or to make (even minor) edits to them. You might be able to get pretty far by crawling the web site as shown here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26286339/firebase-code-pull

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing built into Firebase Hosting for either downloading the existing assets, or to make (even minor) edits to them.

You should be able to get pretty far by crawling the web site as shown here: [Firebase code pull](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26286339/firebase-code-pull).