# i Already hosted a Web page Project to Filebase console using firebase deploy comment , How can i Download the Project files Now?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication, google-cloud-functions

i Already hosted a Web page Project to Filebase console  using firebase deploy comment , How can i Download the Project files Now ?

```
firebase deploy
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**You can not download the project files...**

That you can download is the data/files you have stored in your realtime database or firestore database.

You can switch between deploys as well, you can roll back to older deploy or to the newer depending of your needs, but you can not download any of it.

Answer (score 5):

There is no blanket "code pull" from Firebase, so you will need to take a different approach for each product.

| Product | How to get the code/data |
| --- | --- |
| Hosting | There is no API to get your hosted files back from Firebase, but you can usually get pretty close by crawling the site. See [Pull lost code from Firebase Hosting deployment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26286339/pull-lost-code-from-firebase-hosting-deployment) |
| Realtime Database | You can either use one of the SDKs, use the REST API (for small databases this may be as simple as adding `.json` to the end of the database URL), or you can set up automatic backups and get the data from there. |
| Firestore | You can either use one of the SDKs or REST API here too, or you get export through the console or `gcloud` CLI as explained [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/export-import#export_data) |
| Authentication | You can export all your users through the [Admin SDK](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/manage-users#list_all_users) or the [Firebase CLI](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cli/auth#auth-export) |
| Cloud Functions | The closest you can get here is to copy/paste the code from the Google Cloud console as explained here: [Get code from firebase console which I deployed earlier](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43916490/get-code-from-firebase-console-which-i-deployed-earlier/43916900#43916900) |