# How to pull code from firebase hosting after losing the local code

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-hosting

I am in a trouble here. I want to pull code(static site mainly in js,html) from firebase hosting. I have lost the local code folder. I have researched on the internet but could not find any method to do this work. Is it possible that I can pull the code from firebase hosting?

can anyone please guide me?

Answer (score 1):

I found two solutions first is here :
https://stackoverflow.com/a/26287429/12863176

The second is to reach the firebase support they will provide you with the files
https://groups.google.com/g/firebase-talk/c/BmuJioZbv5o