# Firebase project backup

Tags: firebase, backup

I've mistakenly deleted an app in which folder I've stored my firebase project (that is hosted). Is there a way to backup all firebase project files using VSC terminal?

I've tried using ChatGPT but commands he's suggesting are not working.

Comment: If you're using Firebase hosting, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26286339. If you're using Cloud Functions, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43916490/get-code-from-firebase-console-which-i-deployed-earlier/43916900#43916900